# Comma Code program in Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python by working my way through 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'. I'm currently at chapter 4. The practice project I'm currently trying to build is as follows:

> Say you have a list value like this:
>   spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
>   Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

I have tried to find some answers online, but the programs online look very different from the one I have written. I was wondering how to fix my program. Currently it is only returning the first list item to me. Here is my code:

```
randomlist = []
while True:
    print('Add something to the list: ')
    listitem = input()
    if listitem == '':
        break
    randomlist = randomlist + [listitem]

def commaplacer(somelist): #function
    for i in range(len(somelist)): #this reiterates the list
        if len(somelist)>i:
            return somelist[i]
        elif len(somelist)==i:
            return 'and' + somelist[i] 
        else:
            break

result = commaplacer(randomlist)
print(result)
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `return` from a function, it means you don't want it to run any more. I think your `return` statements cause it to exit before you intend.

Instead, I think you should initialize your `output` as an empty string and then build it up as you move through the list. At the end of the loop, `return output` to send the completed string back.

I think your loop logic can be simplified to 2 cases. Either the item is the last in the list `len(somelist)-1 == i` and we need to add the `'and'` or it is not the last item and we just need to put a comma.

Here's an example:

```py
randomlist = ['Lions', 'tigers', 'bears, oh my!']


def commaplacer(somelist):  # function
    output = ''
    for i in range(len(somelist)):
        if len(somelist)-1 == i:
            output += 'and ' + somelist[i]
        else:
            output += somelist[i] + ', '
    return output


result = commaplacer(randomlist)
print(result)
```

will output

```
Lions, tigers, and bears, oh my!
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what exactly does the 'output' command? I believe I didn't learn that command yet. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The `output` inside of the function is just a variable-name that is initialized before the loop, so that the variable's scope is "outside" of the loop. When you then call `output += 'and '` or something like that, you are appending that information to the variable `output` outside of the loop. You can name that variable anything you would like.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have an additional question. edit: Why did you use ```if len(somelist)-1 == i```? Instead of just ```if len(somelist)==i``` Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Sami Imagine a `somelist` has 3 items, the `len(somelist)` will be `3`. However, when we iterate through the list, we access items in the list starting from `0`. The 3 values in the list are accessed via `somelist[0]`, `somelist[1]`, and `somelist[2]`. In the example program above, we use a variable `i` instead of a specific number (i.e. `somelist[i]`), but `i` will have the values `0`, then `1`, and finally `2`. `i` will never be equal to `3` unless `somelist` has more than 3 elements.

Comment: @Sami The short version is that I know Python lists are zero-indexed and so I know that `length-1` is the last element in the list. Python, Java, C++, JavaScript and many other languages work this way (start from 0). There are some languages, such as FORTRAN, that start from 1 so it's just something to be aware of for whatever language you're writing your code in.

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = []
def coma(listName):
    output = ''
    for i in range(len(listName):
        if i==0:
            output = listName[i]
        elif i == len(listName) -1:
            output += ', and ' + listName[i]
        else:
            output += ', ' + listName[i]
    return output
print(coma(spam))
```

Comment: Your answer would be improved with an [edit] to add an explanation as to how this answer improves the existing, accepted answer.

Comment: in case if we have [] or a single value in a list we have to consider this condition as well, by including additional elif statement.

Comment: @mabute, isn't this the same as the answer already provided by WGriffing

Comment: I try to modify it in case your list only have one value, in that case the print result will not have the unnecessary comma

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate the code to 3 lines in the function.

```
def commaplacer(somelist): #function
    if not somelist: return ''
    elif len(somelist) == 1: return somelist[0]
    else: return ', '.join(somelist[:-1])+', and ' + somelist[-1]

#line 1: check if list is empty. If yes, return empty string

#line 2: check if list has only one value. If yes, return only first value

#line 3: since list has more than one value, use 'join' function
#join all values until last one. add ', and ' then add last value
```

Now you can call the function to get the desired result.

```
result = commaplacer(randomlist)
print(result)
```

The result will be:

```
#when you enter nothing, you get an empty string in return
>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> 
>>> 

#when you enter only one value to the list
>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> good
>>> 
>>> good

#when you enter a few values to the list

>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> apple
>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> banana
>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> carrot
>>> Add something to the list: 
>>> egg
Add something to the list: 

apple, banana, carrot, and egg
```